# Customize the maven surefire XHTML report

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin

I am using Apache Maven for automation purposes, after test automation finishes, XHTML and surefire HTML reports are generated.

I would like to customize the surefire HTML report according to my format, eg.: placing our company logo, attaching screen shot, etc.

Is there a way to customize my report through java code? I came across XMLPARSER ... can any one provide me a good link or guide me how to do this modification.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to configure the layout is via the [site descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/sitedescriptor.html) but not for single report like you mentoined.

Update:
What i missed to say that you can change the [complete design of the site](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creatingskins.html) if you like to. May be it helps to see an [example](http://maven.apache.org/skins/maven-fluido-skin/).